# How can I modify text in a div?

Tags: html, css

I've created a `<div>` with an ID of "footer" and put three `<h3>` elements inside of it.

How can I modify the text? I've managed to apply `top` and `font-size` but I want to space the words.

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Height of the footer */
  height: 86px;
  /* color: white;
     Changed for this demo */
  color: black;
}

#footer>h3 {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Word 1</h3>
  <h3>Word 2</h3>
  <h3>Word 3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "i want to space the words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to apply the **[`margin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** to your `<h3>` tags. By specifying two values such as `margin: 0 20px`, you can state that you only want the margin to apply horizontally and not vertically:

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  color: black;
}

#footer > h3 {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Word 1</h3>
  <h3>Word 2</h3>
  <h3>Word 3</h3>
</div>
```

If you only want the marign to be **between** the text (so that the outer edges aren't taken into consideration), you can use the pseudo-selector **[`:not(:first-of-type)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** to only target elements that aren't the first, and then simply apply a **[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left)** to these:

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  color: black;
}

#footer > h3 {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
}

#footer > h3:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Word 1</h3>
  <h3>Word 2</h3>
  <h3>Word 3</h3>
</div>
```

NB: I've changed the `color` to `black` so that the text can be seen.

Comment: I actually did it with ``padding``. In this case do you think it matters? I dont know a reason why to choose one over the other

Comment: The difference is in the [**box model**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model). `padding` affects the element's **content** while `margin` affects the element **itself**. Borders sit in between, so if you want a border around an element, you may find you need a specific one of the two :)

Comment: So pretty much in this case it doesnt matter. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add some padding or margin to you `<h3>` element

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
#footer {
   text-align: center;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:86px;   /* Height of the footer */
   color:black;
}  

#footer > h3 {
    top:20px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:30px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Word 1</h3>
  <h3>Word 2</h3>
  <h3>Word 3</h3>
</div>
```